# Trabajar con números con decimales en coma PHP

Tags: php

el problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de nominas, por ende trabajo con valores de montos como 5.434,05 (es el formato que se trabaja en mi pais, puntos para los miles y comas para los decimales) un ejemplo de lo que haría el sistema, seria calcular un bono para hijos, que poseen todos los trabajadores, el calculo para ese bono, es el numero de hijos, por un monto especifico, por ejemplo 2.000,00

Si lo formulo en php sin comas o puntos seria:

```
<?php $hijos=2; $bono=2000; $calculo= $hijo * $bono; echo "Su bono por hijo es: $calculo";?>
```

Hasta allí perfecto, pero que pasa si el 2000 lo tengo que guardar y mostrar como 2.000,00??

Hacer el calculo no funciona, por que solo me toma el primer 2, ademas de que todo el sistema tengo que mostrarlo en el formato con puntos y comas incluyendo en la BD que tengo.

Que podría hacer en ese caso? habrá forma de formatear el valor y que me muestre el resultado con decimales?

*Gracias...!*

Comment: Entonces, en tu base de datos se guarda por ejemplo 2000, pero tienes problema para traerlo de regreso a la vista y hacer operaciones con el?

Comment: @Aprendiz en la BD lo puedo guardar con puntos y comas (aunque me han mencionado antes que no es recomendable) pero el problema mas que nada es a la hora de hacer operaciones matematicas, php no me las ejecuta con puntos ni comas

Comment: @Aprendiz no, simplemente toma el primer numero, es decir el 2, osea si lo traigo de la BD como "2.000,00" lo multiplico por 2, me da 4 nada mas, osea los ceros no los reconoce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi recomendación es la siguiente:

Opción:

- No guardes los números con dicho formato, *eso deberías hacerlo a nivel de vista* con las funciones que MySQL o PHP tengan disponibles; por que así parece que estás comprometiéndolos desde que los almacenas y ante un cambio de estructura posterior eso daría problemas.
- Puedes guardarlos como `INT` de este modo: Por ejemplo: `2000`

Una vez hecho lo anterior tu *script* de PHP debería quedar de este modo:

```
<?php

$hijos=2; 
$bono= 2000; //representación del valor obtenido de la **BD**


$calculo= $hijos * $bono; 

$res = number_format($calculo, 2, ',', '.');
echo "Su bono por hijo es: $res";
```

- El valor obtenido de la base de datos debería ser: `2000` mostrado como número entero.
- Realizamos la multiplicación de `$hijos * $bono`.
- Originalmente la op. anterior nos dará 4000, pero para formatear la salida podemos usar el método `number_format()` como se muestra.

Te da como resultado lo siguiente:

> Su bono por hijo es: 4.000,00

Comment: Excelente, gracias ya me funciona